# DropZone Does not pick up CSV files on Windows 10 and ChromeOS with MIME "text/csv" filter set

Tags: reactjs, csv, mime, dropzone

When running, testing, and debugging on Linux and macOS - the standard browser file pickers are happy to accept the MIME type "text/csv" to filter for CSV files to upload with DropZone.

Windows 10 (even with Chrome), and ChromeOS (Chrome as well of course) are not happy with this whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a MIME filter like below:

```
<Dropzone
            accept="text/csv"
            onDrop={(accepted, rejected) => { this.setState({ accepted, rejected }); }}
          >
```

Use a file extension filter instead:

```
<Dropzone
            accept=".csv"
            onDrop={(accepted, rejected) => { this.setState({ accepted, rejected }); }}
          >
```

This code is pulled directly from the 'Accept' sample located at: https://react-dropzone.js.org/

Full working modified sample:

```
class Accept extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      accepted: [],
      rejected: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="dropzone">
          <Dropzone
            accept=".csv"
            onDrop={(accepted, rejected) => { this.setState({ accepted, rejected }); }}
          >
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
              <div {...getRootProps()}  className="dropzone">
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <p>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</p>
                <p>Only *.jpeg and *.png images will be accepted</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </Dropzone>
        </div>
        <aside>
          <h4>Accepted files</h4>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.accepted.map(f => <li key={f.name}>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</li>)
            }
          </ul>
          <h4>Rejected files</h4>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.rejected.map(f => <li key={f.name}>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</li>)
            }
          </ul>
        </aside>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

<Accept />
```

Comment: .csv in the accept still triggers the isDragReject prop, but it accepts the file on drop. So onHover, it would show red, but onDrop, it would accept it

Answer (score 7):

Windows recognizes .csv files as a different type, so change your accept string to the following:

```
accept=".csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used ```acceptedFiles={[".csv, text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/csv, text/x-csv, application/x-csv, text/comma-separated-values, text/x-comma-separated-values"]}``` the above did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you use only useDropzone:

```js
const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
  onDrop,
  accept: { "text/csv": [".csv"] },
});
```

It works on Win10, but I haven't tested on Mac

Comment: This worked for me on windows thanks